# Human Stem Cells and Disease

Tags: molecular-biology

Can human stem cells be stored for use by future family members as a way to combat generational diseases like diabetes

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE! What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stem cells can be stored but that is an expensive alternative to generating them freshly. It has been [shown](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11589942) that you can make stem cells from skin cells.

Theoretically, it would be much less expensive to store a piece of epidermis from a recently deceased relative than to make fresh stem cells and store those.

However, the research for generating stem cells from deeply frozen tissues is not there yet. Furthermore, the concept of using stem cells to 'combat disease' is not the right paradigm. It might even be said that some diseases (cancer) are the result of dedifferentiation gone awry.

Where stem cell transplants are used is in the replacement of bone marrow after total body radiation/chemotherapy to destroy marrow (in those cases where the disease has arisen in the marrow). In these cases we rely on the poorly defined process that allows cells to target their microenvironment.

For example, it would not work if marrow replacement cells decided to grow wherever they landed (lungs, liver,etc).

So stem cell storage is an option whose time has passed ,as our tech now allows us to make them.